# How to add text centre of the horizontal portion of a |- line in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to automatically add text to the centre of a horizontal line created with `|-` and I am struggling to see how to do so without having to specify an exact value, this is my effort setting `right=0.6cm` in a `node`:

[image]

How can I align the `failed` to centre of the horizontal line please? I hope you can forgive me if this is a duplicate or extremely basic, it is quite challenging searching for `|-` in search engines, my TikZ magic is still basic-ish and I do not know how to solely target the horizontal line in the `|-` construct, would appreciate a duplicate suggestion if one is available.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1.414cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (one) at (0,0) {Random text};
\node[draw] (two) at (0,-1) {Random text};
\node[draw] (three) at (0,-2) {Random text};
\node[draw] (four) at (0,-3) {Random text};
\draw[-stealth] (one.south) -- (two.north);
\foreach \X in {two,three,four}%
    {\draw[-stealth,color=red] (\X.east) -- ++ (0.3em, 0) |- ([yshift=.6em]two.north) node[right=0.6cm,above] {\textbf{\tiny failed}};}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `pos=.75` or `near end` is the center of the second half.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel worked perfectly in my main document, feel free to post an answer I can accept if you like, thank you for your help. `tikz` is quite the learning curve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments by @Qrrbrbirlbel, setting `near end` worked:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1.414cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (one) at (0,0) {Random text};
\node[draw] (two) at (0,-1) {Random text};
\node[draw] (three) at (0,-2) {Random text};
\node[draw] (four) at (0,-3) {Random text};
\draw[-stealth] (one.south) -- (two.north);
\foreach \X in {two,three,four}%
    {\draw[-stealth,color=red] (\X.east) -- ++ (0.3em, 0) |- ([yshift=.6em]two.north) node[near end,above] {\textbf{\tiny failed}};}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will delete this answer if another answer is posted saying the same thing, I like to maintain my 100% accept rate so have posted a self-answer based on the comments by @Qrrbrbirlbel